# How to remove default action from a plugin?

Tags: plugins, actions

I'm trying to remove the default wordpress action:

```
add_action( 'do_pings', 'do_all_pings', 10, 1 );
```

from `wp-includes/default-filters.php`

This is the code I have (plugin):

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_do_all_pings' );

function remove_do_all_pings() {
  remove_action( 'do_pings', 'do_all_pings' );
}
```

will this work? I have no way of testing because I have no clue how this ping thing works.

Comment: Is the code above working for you? You'll need a way to test, otherwise are you trying to prevent WP sending pings? If so why not ask how to do that?

Comment: Like I said in my post, I am trying to remove a default action, and also like I said in my post, I don't know how to test if it works or not.

Comment: You should mention that in your question, as your question might already be the answer. Keep in mind though that you should ask about problems, not how to fix solutions. If your goal is to disable pingbacks then there are several methods, which makes for higher chances of a response, and more interesting answers

Comment: Note that generally speaking when you are removing filters you must provide the same priority and argument count as the original `add_action`. In this case you are lucky `10` and `1` are the defaults so it will probably still work, but in most cases this will trip you up.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming your question on how to test pings if that is what you are really after.

Comment: @majick, thanks for the info about priority, that is one of the things I was concerned with. What about the 'init' action, is this the appropriate hook? Does it matter which hook I use to trigger the remove_action? Does the 'init' hook trigger before 'do_pings' and remove it before it is triggered?

Comment: `init` should be fine here, of course it totally depends on what you are removing, as of course it has to be added before you can remove it. for a plugin for example you would probably use the `plugins_loaded` hook instead.